# Installing package with composer from git repository

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I am trying to install a package from private repository but I get an error of:

```
Problem 1
- The requested package chef-php-api could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

I have checked for the name issue, there doesn't seem to be a typo issue with a name to me, and I have a set "minimum-stability": "dev" in my composer.json, so not sure what I did wrong.

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "name": "chef-php-api",
        "url": "https://urlOfTheRepository/chef-php-api.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "chef-php-api": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the type be `vcs` and not `git`, or does `git` work?  I'm having problems on this, and i saw `vcs` in the composer docs.  https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives. It seems to be downloading, until it gets to the clone step from the composer tmp dir, then it deletes it from the vendors.  Ok, switching it to `vcs` it has no problems when cloning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `require` section has `"chef-php-api": "*"`. This is not correct for a package. Your require should be in the form of `"vendor/package": "*"`, so make sure to add the vendor section to your require.

If you're unsure of what to add, look at the `name` value in the `composer.json` file for your `chef-php-api` package. That is what you should add to the `require` section.